# How to push data to firestore document?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Basically what I want is that if a document doesn't exist then create a new one (it works fine now) but if a document does exist, push a new object to the existing array.

I was able to get data from documents and console.log them, but don't know how to push new ones to the existing document.

My FB structure looks like this:

```
favorites
  someUserID
    Videos [ 
      0: {
      name: SomeName
      url: SomeUrl
      },

      /* I would like to push new objects like this: */

      1: {
      name: data.name
      url: data.url
      },
    ]
```

This is my current code:

```
const { user } = UserAuth();
const UserID = user.uid;
const favoritesRef = doc(db, "favorites", UserID);

const test = async (data) => {
    try {
        await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
          const sfDoc = await transaction.get(favoritesRef);

          if (!sfDoc.exists()) {
            setDoc(favoritesRef, {
                Videos: [{name: data.name}]    
            });
          }

          /* I got my document content here */

          const newFavorites = await getDoc(favoritesRef);
          console.log("Document data:", newFavorites.data());
         
          /* And would like to push new Data here */
          transaction.update(favoritesRef, { name: data.name});
        });
        console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Transaction failed: ", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out like this:

```
const { user } = UserAuth();
const UserID = user.uid
const favoritesRef = doc(db, "favorites", UserID)

const test = async (data) => {
    try {
        await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
          const sfDoc = await transaction.get(favoritesRef);
          if (!sfDoc.exists()) {
            await setDoc(favoritesRef, {
                favs: [
                    {
                    name: data.name, 
                    ytb: data.ytb, 
                    url: data.url
                }]})
          }
          const doesExists = sfDoc.data().favs.some((fav) => fav.name === data.name)
          console.log(doesExists)
          
          if (doesExists === true)
          
          {
            console.log("AlreadyExist")
          }

          else {
      
          const currentData = sfDoc.data().favs
          
          transaction.update(favoritesRef, {
            favs: [...currentData,
                {
                name: data.name, 
                ytb: data.ytb, 
                url: data.url
            }]}
        )}
        });
        console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Transaction failed: ", e);
      }
      
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

To update the array Firestore now has a function that allows you to [update an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) without writing your code again:

> **Update elements in an array**
>
> If your document contains an array field, you can use `arrayUnion()`
> and `arrayRemove()` to add and remove elements. `arrayUnion()` adds
> elements to an array but only elements not already present.
> `arrayRemove()` removes all instances of each given element.

```
import { doc, updateDoc, arrayUnion, arrayRemove } from "firebase/firestore";

const washingtonRef = doc(db, "cities", "DC");

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
await updateDoc(washingtonRef, {
    regions: arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
});

// Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
await updateDoc(washingtonRef, {
    regions: arrayRemove("east_coast")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but what i usually do is:

I'm adding every user that signs in to an array.

```
 const snapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, "allUsers", "list"));
 const currentUsers = snapshot.data().users;

 await setDoc(doc(db, "allUsers", "list"), {
        users: [...currentUsers, { name, uid: userId, avatar: photo }],
      });
```

I first get the items that exist in the list, and them i create a new one that has every previous item and the ones i'm adding. The currentUsers is the current list in that caso. Maybe you should try thist instead of `Videos: [{name: data.name}]`

```
setDoc(favoritesRef, {
                Videos: [...currentVideos, {name: data.name}]    
                })
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense! I will try it in the morning and let know, thanks!

Comment: It works but doesnt create new document when its not created yet

Comment: What you could do is create in the firebase console a new document with all of those properties, and then just add the new ones to that document.